# Alamofire get request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to hit an API with the below alamofire request with headers passed as parameters. but it's not happening

```
let url = "http://192.168.1.42/api/v1/userConfig/8b5dbf7d9bdd40d29472be44efa9b7d3"
let secondTok: String = String(Token.get())


let bear = "Bearer " + secondTok

let param = ["Content-Type" : "application/json","Accept" : "application/json", "Authorization" : bear]



Alamofire.request(url, method: .get , parameters: param , encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
```

Comment: What is wrong? Do you get an error? What is the response you receive? _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._ See [What is On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're making get parameters. Set it to headers instead

```
let url = "http://192.168.1.42/api/v1/userConfig/8b5dbf7d9bdd40d29472be44efa9b7d3"
let secondTok: String = String(Token.get())
let bear = "Bearer " + secondTok
let headers = ["Content-Type" : "application/json","Accept" : "application/json", "Authorization" : bear]

   Alamofire.request(url, method: .get , headers: param , encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
```

Comment: . i got json data after hitting the api using the above Alamofire request. can  you suggest any method to store recieved json data into core data and display them onto text field.

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire Using get Method

```
Alamofire.request("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) -> Void in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let data = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    self.array = data["contacts"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>
                }
//                self.data = response.result.value as? [String, AnyObject]
                break
            case .failure:
                print("Error")
            }
            if self.array.count > 0 {
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like This with header authorization

```
let url = "http://192.168.1.42/api/v1/userConfig/8b5dbf7d9bdd40d29472be44efa9b7d3"
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + secondTok!,
        "Accept": "application/json"
     ]
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: "" as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
```

Comment: its working now. i did not understand the meaning of parameters: "" as? [String : AnyObject]

Comment: blank parameter consider

Comment: now i am getting json data(lot of data). i need only certain things in them and store them in coredata. can you suggest a method for it.

Comment: what you want from data array or json?

Comment: please use this it easy to store in coredata https://github.com/3lvis/DATAStack you just call with function and add data

Comment: if you have any query in json data how to populate then let me know

Comment: also this library easy to use https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore with example so please check

Comment: its like i have data in which i need only sp name (service provider) under it vo name (venue owner) and under it ve name (venue). these are stored in our local server. i need to store them in core data and reterive them onto 3 text field.

Comment: they said to create class to store the json data and then onto to core data.

Comment: using table view or simple?

Comment: simple 3 text field. once login page is done it moves to next page with 3 text field which should show the data which i received after hitting the api . data is stored in the local server. i have received the data. printed it to the debug area to check.

Comment: why you store in database ? just use userdefault

Comment: there is lot of data. used user default for store jwt token. they want to store in core data, because next time when they login they want to retrieve it from core data instead of hitting again the api.

Comment: i have example for FMDB if you want them?

Comment: please send . we cant extend the comments any more. there is a limit. my mail id sunrazey@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire has method what receive headers as parameter. Use it instead of putting header inside parameter.

```
public func request(
    _ url: URLConvertible,
    method: HTTPMethod = .get,
    parameters: Parameters? = nil,
    encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
    headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
    -> DataRequest
```